# Issues concerning 'brew link numpy'

Tags: python, macos, numpy, homebrew

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I have a problem with `brew link numpy`. I have installed the latest python but it still uses python 2.7. With the error logs shown below, with what ever way I did, I'm still stuck here. Furthermore, I have a problem installing opencv functionalities with the current python environment on my mac.

```
Error: Could not symlink lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/LICENSE.txt
Target /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/LICENSE.txt
already exists. You may want to remove it:
rm '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/LICENSE.txt'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
brew link --overwrite numpy

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run numpy
```

Comment: What do you mean " it still uses python 2.7"? Is part of your problem that it's installing numpy for python 2 instead of python 3?

Comment: I want the default version to be python 3.6 or the latest version, but the default is python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 different versions of python you should create a virtual environment for each flavor of python.

If python 3.6 was installed using Anaconda, search the Anaconda documentation for creating virtual environment.

If you installed python 3.6 another way, there are unix commands to create virtual environments.

You can create one environment for python 2.7 and another for python 3.6. Activate whichever version you want to run.